# Mongoose : Match, Group, Project weirdness

Tags: mongoose

Starting to explore the wonders of Mongo...

So my goal is simple : get the total number of, let's say, page views by page owner (just an example, working with a similar concept).

It would look something like

```
SELECT SUM(views) FROM page WHERE user_id = 123;
```

Or something like that in MySQL.

So I'm doing something similar with MongoDB and the Mongoose NodeJS package :

```
Page.aggregate([
    { $match : { user_id : 123 } },
    { $group : { _id : null, viewGroup : { $addToSet : "$views" } } },
    { $project : { view_total : { $sum : "$viewGroup" } } }
], (err, result) => { ... });
```

Here's the weird part : it works, but only if at least one of the document's "views" property has a value > 1.

So say I have two docs :

```
{ page_id : 1, user_id : 123, views : 1 }
{ page_id : 2, user_id : 123, views : 1 }
```

The result I get is **1**.

Say I have these two docs :

```
{ user_id : 123, views : 1 }
{ user_id : 123, views : 2 }
```

The result I get is **3**.

I must be approaching this wrong. Any help?

Comment: Not sure I follow. What is the problem again ? Both the expected output are correct for the query you've. Can you show an example where it doesn't work ? Did you intend to use $push and not $addToSet ?

Comment: My friend, you hold the answer. I didn't intend to use $push, but $push enables the intended outcome.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Veeram in the comment, `$push` should have been used instead of `$addToSet`. I didn't realize `$addToSet` only added unique values, where `$push` simply pushes each value to the array which is what I want.